# Why are these log statements preventing my doPost() function from adding a line to a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, debugging, logging

I have a Google Apps Script which posts to a Google Sheet from a Godot project. The doPost() looks like this:

```
function doPost(params) {
  const { date, time, cate, amount, desc, sheetname } = params.parameter

  var sheet       = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetname)

  if(typeof params == 'undefined') {
    Logger.log("This seems to be undefined: " + params.parameter);
    console.Log("This seems to be undefined: " + params.parameter);
  } else {
    Logger.log("No params are 'undefined'")
    console.Log("No params are 'undefined'")
  }

  sheet.appendRow([date,time,cate,amount,desc,"hang on, what"])
}
```

Note the if/else block in the centre. If I comment this out, the doPost works correctly, and adds another line to the Google Sheet. If I leave it in, then I get two problems:

1. I can't find or read where the error messages are logged - they just seem to vanish into the ether and
2. The final line of the program, 'sheet.appendRow(etc' is never called, and the new line is never added to the sheet.

Does anybody know how to solve these issues? I'm currently following a process of elimination here, but a knowledgeable reply would be appreciated...!

EDIT:

I've replaced the params 'undefined' test with the 'bulletproof' test from [this page](https://%20https://code.tutsplus.com/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-empty-in-javascript--cms-37053t), as suggested by NEWAZA:

```
function isEmptyObject(value) {
  const type = typeof value
  const isObject = value != null && type === 'object' 
  return isObject && Object.keys(value).length === 0;
}
```

I've also implemented the Try/Catch suggestion from Cooper, below.

By process of elimination, I've found that if I include

```
console.Log
```

in the function, the function silently falls over and the doPost fails.

I've commented this out (might remove it later, if I don't find out how to use it properly), but I still can't seem to find where to read Logger.log messages unless I'm running the script from within the editor, which has limited functionality for me.

Comment: spreadsheet is undefined

Comment: add a try/catch and Logger.log() the errors or possibly look at executions

Comment: 'Spreadsheet' is defined earlier in the program as a const, which is accessible by the function in question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
function doPost(params) {
  try {
    const { date, time, cate, amount, desc, sheetname } = params.parameter
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    sheet.appendRow([date, time, cate, amount, desc, "hang on, what"])
    if (typeof params == 'undefined') {
      Logger.log("This seems to be undefined: " + params.parameter);
    } else {
      Logger.log("No params are 'undefined'")
    }
  }
  catch(x) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, implemented that, but sadly it just continues to silently fall over when console.Log is NOT commented out.

Comment: Perhaps it was the capital L in Log.  I believe it is supposed to be lowercase.  Try catch would have caught that.

Comment: You're correct, console.log should use a lowercase 'l' - the function now executes and posts when console.log is not commented out. Still not sure where the logged comments are *going*, but at least nothing's a showstopper now. I've had no output from the 'try/catch' yet, but I guess that suggests that things are working? =/

Comment: Cooper, I'm still not sure how to get the log outside of running the code within the Google Apps Script editor - but you've solved the showstopper issue I was dealing with. If you'd like to edit your answer to highlight the 'lower case L' issue, I can mark it as correct.